# What non-WMD weapons were Saddam Hussein prohibited from buying?

Tags: international-relations, international-law, international, united-nations, iraq

The Wikipedia page of UNSCR 1441 (the last one before the invasion, reiterating what had been said in previous resolutions and giving a 'final chance') says this:

> Iraq's breaches related not only to weapons of mass destruction (WMD), but also the known construction of prohibited types of missiles, the purchase and import of prohibited armaments and ...

What were the 'prohibited armaments' referenced here?

Comment: Take a look at [UNSCR 687, paragraph 24,25](https://www.un.org/depts/unmovic/documents/687.pdf)